# Are probability distributions available in Torch C++ (libtorch)?

Tags: libtorch

I am trying to port a Q-network, and it uses probability distribution sampling (`Normal` class in Python and its `rsample` function). Are these available in PyTorch C++?

Answer (score 0):

As of now, there is not yet a frontend for distributions in libtorch (you can check the Namespaces [here](https://pytorch.org/cppdocs/api/library_root.html#class-hierarchy)).
Apparently it's on the roadmap for a future update according to [this thread](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/torch-distributions-categorical/45747/5).
There are links to the internal C++ implementations of distributions in that thread as well.

Answer (score 0):

The normal distribution is kinda available in the C++ frontend with the `torch::randn` (normal distribution, mean=0 and deviation=1) function, though it does not indeed provide the `rsample` functionnality. You will have to implemented the reparameterization trick yourself, but that should not take more than a couple lines of code.